# lightning:Datatable Spring18 problem in Customer Community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, customer-community, lightning-datatable

Spring18 broke the URL field in my Customer Community.  I have a simple data table that renders a list with a URL.  After Spring18 the data table works fine in the standard UI but when I put the same component into the Customer Community UI the link is not clickable.

In the Salesforce Lightning "normal" UI the Link is rendered as:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" title="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" tabindex="-1">Click to Download</a>
```

In the Customer Community the link is rendered as:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" title="https://www.google.com" target="_blank" tabindex="-1">Click to Download</a>
```

Why am I seeing the "javascript:void(0);" in the customer community?  It is the exact same lightning component showing the same list ... Just in the base community (Standard Lightning UI) vs. a Napili template Customer Community?

It is a simple component just to test this out ...

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome"> 
    <aura:attribute name="list" type="ContentVersion[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="Object"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this }" action="{!c.init }"/>
    <lightning:datatable data="{!v.list}"
        columns="{!v.columns}"
        keyField="Id"
        hideCheckboxColumn="true"
    /> 
</aura:component>
```

Here's the client-side controller:

```
({
    init: function (component, event, helper) {
               component.set("v.columns", [
                {label: 'Title', fieldName: 'Title', type: 'text'},
                {label: 'File Type', fieldName: 'FileType', type: 'text'},
                {label: 'Download Link', fieldName: 'ContentDocumentId', type: 'url', typeAttributes: { label: 'Click to Download' }}
                ]);
        component.set('v.list', [{
                id: 'a',
                Title: 'Google',
                FileType: 'Cool',
                ContentDocumentId: 'https://www.google.com'
            },
            {
                id: 'b',
                Title: 'CNN',
                FileType: 'NotCool',
                ContentDocumentId: 'http://cnn.com'
            }]);
    },
})
```

This is in my Spring18 Sandbox ... And even more painful is that it appeared to work correctly in Winter.  The URL field rendered and was clickable.  Of course the title did not render back then.  Any thoughts on what I could be doing wrong?  Why is the URL field in a datatable not populating the HREF portion of the anchor tag in a Customer Community?

Comment: I have tested this scenario on my environment and I am facing the same problem - this looks like a bug to me

Comment: Well it is broken in production and my Sandbox now.  Bug still exists in Spring '18 Patch 6.10 and Spring '18 Patch 6.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed now that patch 7.x is available.